# module_load_include not working including inc file

Tags: 6, debugging

I am trying to make it work, but it seems simply not working in Drupal 6. Maybe this is the issue, it does not work on D6?

This is the code:

```
// $file_path = module_load_include('inc', 'MYMODULE.inc', 'includes/MYMODULE.inc');
$file_path = module_load_include('MYMODULE', 'MYMODULE.inc');

// Testing.
if ($file_path === FALSE) {
  dpm('Failed to include: ' . $filename);
}
else {
  dpm('Successfully included: ' . $file_path);
}
```

I have tried also adding a drupal_load before and some other things, like changing params, moving the inc file to the root module folder and so, but I allways get the same:

```
Failed to include: sites/all/modules/MYCOMPANY/MYMODULE/MYMODULE.module
```

any idea of what am I doing wrong?

Thanks a log.

Answer (score 7):

You need to add `inc` into your implementation of the function.  Also you don't need to add the extension `.inc` as part of the filename:

```
$file_path = module_load_include('inc', 'MYMODULE', 'FILENAME');
```

Documentation: [`module_load_include();`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/6).

Answer (score 4):

The arguments expected from [module_load_include()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/7) are, in order, the following:

- The extension of the file to load
- The name of the module whose directory is looked for the file
- The name of the file (without extension)

In your case, the call to `module_load_include()` should be:

- `module_load_include('inc', 'MYMODULE', 'includes/MYMODULE')`, in the first case
- `module_load_include('inc', 'MYMODULE')` in  the second case

In the first case, the loaded file is includes/MYMODULE.inc, contained in the "includes" directory contained in the directory containing MYMODULE.module; in the second case, the file is MYMODULE.inc contained in the same directory containing MYMODULE.module.

When the third argument is not passed, the name of the file is the name of the module without .module extension.